# Sencha Touch , Phonegap - App Icon not working

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2.2, sencha-command

I am building my sencha + phonegap app using the sencha command utility. I have updated the config.xml in the root of the sencha app with the following information to have my app icon.

```
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
<icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="resources/icons/android/icon-36.png" />
<icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="resources/icons/android/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="resources/icons/android/icon-72.png" />
<icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="resources/icons/android/icon-96.png" />
```

When i run the sencha command to build the app,

```
sencha app build native
```

The built package still has the phonegap icon when installed onto the device. The phonegap folder is copied with all the images i specified in the config.xml.

This is using the phonegap local build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the phonegap cli. If you are using phonegap local build, the icons and startup images should be copied manually to the `phonegap/platforms/<platform>/res/drawable-<res>` folder. Look at the bug here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/58.

I have copied my icons to the respective folder and the build is having the right icons.

If you are using the phonegap cloud build, this will work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Icons and splash screens will only work from config.xml when using phonegap build.

Comment: yes i can -> http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html and in particular you are interested in whichever platform you are working on, it all states copy the images into whatever folder.